# Can i format a new SSD on my ps3 using an AV cable?

Tags: ps3, hdmi

My HDMI port does not work, but the AV does.I was using an AV cable but i have to swap my old hdd for a new ssd and now i do not have an image though the AV cable.

The old HDD was sold an i have no access to it anymore. My doubt is...Can i access the "bios" of the console to format my ssd through the AV cable or this part of the system can only be displayed on the HDMI?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can access Safe Mode without an HDMI Cable, as the video signal will be sent to both the HDMI and Multi AV ports simultaneously. To do that, just enter Safe Mode by following this set of steps:

1. Completely turn off the PS3
2. Press and hold the Power Button, until the console turns off again (it should beep 3 separate times and then turn off)
3. Press and hold the Power Button until you hear two continuous short beeps

If the Safe Mode screen does not appears, you could try resetting the video settings in a similar way:

1. Completely turn off the PS3
2. Press and hold the Power Button until you hear the second beep (it will beep once when you start holding the Power Button and one more time a couple of seconds later, when you hear the second one let it go)

Answer (score 0):

The usual method when changing hard drives in the ps3 or ps4 is to download from the playstation website, using a pc, the playstation firmware onto a usb stick formatted to fat32. Install the new hard drive and insert the usb stick. Switch on the ps3/4 and it should boot from the usb stick and install the new software.